# Javascript setInterval not waiting before running function

Tags: javascript, delay, setinterval

Here's my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        window.onload = function() {            

        function obtenirTOC(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://saaprod/soutien_tache/outils/preferencesAO/tocCheck.asp", 
                success: function(str){
                if (str=="Oui"){
                    $("#show-hide-navigation").click();
                    }
                }
            })

        }
            setInterval(obtenirTOC(),30000);
}
        //-->
        </script>
```

My code is not waiting 30000 ms like it's supposed to. It's running as soon as i load the page.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: because you're calling the function straight away via the parenthesis ( '()' ), wrap it like so function(){ obtenirTOC()})

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't do what you think:

```
setInterval(obtenirTOC(),30000);
```

This is executing the function immediately and setting the interval to execute the *return value* of the function.  (Which in this case is `undefined`.)  Instead, just pass the function reference itself:

```
setInterval(obtenirTOC,30000);
```